# Why a function returns the same output with different passed argument

Tags: javascript

I am beginner at JS and came across a code which gives the same output if I put different argument here is the code:

```js
function addToArr(element) {
  var arr = [];
  arr.push(element);
  return element + " added to " + arr;
}

var firstPass = addToArr("a");
var secondPass = addToArr("b");
console.log(firstPass); // a added to a
console.log(secondPass); // a added to a
```

AS you can see from the above code if I pass `a` and then `b` but I get the same output WHY?

Comment: `secondPass` is not `"a added to a"`. It’s `"b added to b"`.

Comment: There is an observation that the array is reset every time you call the function, but that’s not what this question is currently asking about. The answers address the “wrong” issue, so long as the question has the incorrect `secondPass` output and no clear problem statement (other than the incorrect one); thus it should be put on hold or fixed, before being answered.

Comment: I ran the same code and getting expected results. `firstPass` as `"a added to a"` and `secondPass` as `"b added to b"`.

Comment: yes, I am agreed with @SebastianSimon，I tested your code, but the output is different，firstPass is a added to a, secondPass is b added to b. Your code is fine. Why do you say the output is the same?

Answer (score 0):

Before getting into your example, I will give you a general answer: A function can have the same return value for different inputs. For example, 3 is odd, 5 is odd as well. If you have an isOdd function, then it should yield true both for 3 and 5.

Now, your example:

```
function addToArr(element) {
  var arr = [];
  arr.push(element);
  return element + " added to " + arr;
}

var firstPass = addToArr("a");
var secondPass = addToArr("b");
console.log(firstPass); // a added to a
console.log(secondPass); // a added to a
```

is not yielding a added to a, but b added to b at the second call, at least to me. However, you need to have a separate array, like this:

```
function addToArr(arr, element) {
  var str = `[${arr.toString()}]`;
  arr.push(element);
  return element + " added to " + str;
}

var arr = [];
var firstPass = addToArr(arr, "a");
var secondPass = addToArr(arr, "b");
console.log(firstPass); // a added to a
console.log(secondPass); // a added to a
```

because declaring an empty array inside the function and adding a value to it makes no sense.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the additions to the array to "stick," then one option would be to change the signature of your function to accept an input array.  Then, have the function add elements to that external array.

```js
function addToArr(element, arr) {
  arr.push(element);
  return element + " added to " + arr;
}

var arr = [];
var firstPass = addToArr("a", arr);
var secondPass = addToArr("b", arr);
console.log(firstPass);  // a added to a
console.log(secondPass); // b added to a,b
console.log(arr);
```